# How to use own SMTP servers PHP mail

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am using default PHP [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function to send emails as below . I have two email servers. How can I set my code to use these two mail server? I am running my PHP code on Linux.

```
mail($currEmail, $HOT_EMAIL_SUBJECT, $body, 'From: '.$pollsConfig_senderEmail);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PEAR::Mail](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.intro.php), you can specify a SMTP server with it.

```
$headers = array ('From'    => $from,
                  'To'      => $to,
                  'Subject' => $subject);

$obj = Mail::factory ('smtp',
                       array ('host' => $host,
                              'port' => $port));

$obj->send ($to, $headers, $body);
```

Comment: I have two smtp servers can I use them both anyway with this package ?

Comment: @SoneshDabhi: Sure, just use two objects.

Comment: Is there any way to use them randomly ?